# Error running npm to generate a package in an ADO repository to allow it to create pipelines via terraform

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, terraform, npm-install

What am I missing that I am getting the error listed below, after performing the following to create a package in a repo?

EDIT: This is specifically happening to me, even though it works for other DevOps technicians on the team.

Made sure I was using the nodejs version this was built on, 12.x.
Made sure I had a valid PAT so I was not getting a 401 permissions error.
Even created a whole new PAT and created a new .npmrc file at the root of my path, everything else works (I can push builds, pull from origin, etc. with no errors.)

Cloned the repo locally
Did a clean git pull origin
made sure I had no commits pending

All this ought to do is create the package we use for Terraform in the repo:
From the root directory of the local copy of the repo, execute

npm i @rootdevops/web-builds --no-save --registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/parentdir/parent_repo_name/_packaging/eudevops/npm/registry/

After you run this command, there will be a .rootdevops folder in the root directory of your project.

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\me\A-Web-Landlord\node_modules\@rootdevops\web-builds
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./scripts/install.js
npm ERR! removing last [.rootdevops.backup] folder...
npm ERR! renaming [.rootdevops] as [.rootdevops.backup]...
npm ERR! installing devops package...
npm ERR! internal/fs/utils.js:779
npm ERR!   throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
npm ERR!     at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1460:5)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\A-Web-Landlord\node_modules\@rootdevops\web-builds\scripts\install.js:31:5)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
npm ERR!     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
npm ERR! }
```

This is what is in the install.js

```
// read version from package.json and save to installFolder
const packageJson = fse.readFileSync(`${nodePkgFolder}/package.json`);
const package = JSON.parse(packageJson);
fse.writeFileSync(`${installFolder}/pkg_version.txt`, package._id);
```

package.json triggers the install.js with this

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "node ./scripts/install.js",
    "release": "npm version patch && npm publish"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was quite strange: for some reason, the developer package we were working with was using fs-extra 4.0.2.

From VS Code, I deleted it and committed, ran the npm i command and it pulled 9.1.0 and ran that and then everything worked.

We don't use that version, so I suspect that the development team for the web UI was referencing an older version as this is an upgrade project of something older.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing package._id to package.id? it seems like the value you are trying to write is undefined (_id prop doesn't exists)

Comment: the package.json in a delivered NPM package is different from a project package.json.  It is defined and works for other people.